# Group mysql results in groups of four

Tags: php, mysql

I want to group the result of a sql select in groups of four rows to make dynamically something like this:

```
<div>
4 rows of the database
</div>
```

For example, if I have 19 rows in the database, I want to create 4 divs (the last one with the 3 remaining rows). This is for a bootstrap gallery, and the div will have the class .row with 4 columns (the four results from the database). I have 8 images, two divs with the class .row need to be created.

I think this will be achieved with loops, but I can´t find the way.

NOTE: i have coded in a very simplistic way, only to try to explain what I'm looking for.
Thanks to all in advance!!

Comment: sounds like an x-y problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: use the LIMIT part of your SQL statement like LIMIT 0, 4 for the first page and LIMIT 4, 4 second statment

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [modulus-operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to group your rows into groups of 4, like this:

```
$i=0;
while($row = ...) {
    if($i%4 == 0) { // % = modulus operator. This returns the remainder of a division, so 1%4 = 1 (because it's 0+1/4), while 5%4 also returns 2 (5%4 = 1+1/4)
       if($i > 0) {
          echo '</div>';
       }
       echo '<div>';
   }
   echo $row;
   $i++;
}
echo '</div>';
```

This will group your results in sets of 4 like so:
`<div>row 1 row 2 row 3 row 4</div><div>row 5 row 6 row 7 row 8</div>` etc.

Comment: Thanks very much!! I have been thinking also about the modulus operator but i always ended with a script that did not work. This answer has worked fine. Thanks again!