# How to loop foreach inside loop div

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, nested-loops

i want to create  and tabel every showing 3 data from db and continue the next db. exp swiper 1 : (1,2,3) , Swiper 2 : (4,5,6) etc.
is it possible to loop a div and have a foreach in it? or any solution. Thanks

```
<div class="swiper-slide">
<table class="table table-image">
    <tbody>
        <?php
             foreach ($branch as $branchs) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="w-25">
                <img
                    src="image/icon/<?= $branchs['imgtitle']; ?>"
                    class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"
                    alt="Sheep">
            </td>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <b><?= $branchs['title']; ?></b>
                </h4>
                <p class="card-text"><?= $branchs['text']; ?>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you actually want here. What do you mean by "and continue the next db"? Are you reading data from multiple databases here?

Comment: Or are you simply trying to say, that you have _one_ set of records, and want to output those in "groups" of three? That can easily be done by keeping a loop counter, and using the modulo operator.

Comment: Thx for help, Yes i want to output those in "groups" of three. Every three data from array database create div again

Comment: And example how to do this using the modulo operator can be found here, https://stackoverflow.com/q/22697509/1427878

Comment: @daunbabadotan Can you show expected HTML? Looks like array_chunk can make things a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a "swipper-slide" and a "swipper-pagination" div every 3 "branchs", this code will loop en the full html and break every 3. You can move HTML code if it is not exactly what you are looking for, but hope that will help.

```php
<?php $counter = 0; $last = count($branch) - 1; ?>
<?php foreach ($branch as $branchs): ?>
    <?php if (!($counter % 3)): ?>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
        <table class="table table-image">
        <tbody>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="w-25">
            <img
                src="image/icon/<?= $branchs['imgtitle']; ?>"
                class="img-fluid img-thumbnail"
                alt="Sheep">
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>
                <b><?= $branchs['title']; ?></b>
            </h4>
            <p class="card-text"><?= $branchs['text']; ?>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php $counter ++; ?>
    <?php if (($counter === $last) || !($counter % 3)): ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thaks, i can fix with this.